# Entity Framework SQL statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to query the table `News` from the database called `StiriDB`. There I want take all the entries that have in the `Description` field the word `Stored` in `SearchTxt`. I can't quite figure out what the `SqlQuery` method wants from me ... This is the code:

```
public IQueryable<News> GetProducts()
{
    var _db = new SiteStiri.Models.NewsContext();
    String SearchTxt = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Cauta"]);
    String queryTxt = "Select * from StiriDB.News where Description like '%" + SearchTxt + "%'";
    IQueryable<News> query = _db.News.SqlQuery<News>(queryTxt);

    if ("DesDate".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.ReleaseDate);
    }

    if ("AsDate".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(u => u.ReleaseDate);
    }

    if ("AsAlp".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(u => u.NewsTitle);
    }

    if ("DesApl".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.NewsTitle);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Additional details : `GetProducts` is called by a ListView. `SearchTxt` is taken with `QueryString` of `Request` because it's an URL attribute. The many ifs are for sorting the data in ascending and descending order based on certain criteria (the ifs work, I just need the `SqlQuery` to work as intended);

Comment: No!!! DON'T create SQL query strings if you're using Linq-to-EF; you're losing all the benefits (compiled queries + parametric queries that prevent SQL injection). Use Linq syntax!!

Comment: Oh i don't really know , i am a newbie. And i am learning by myself so bits and pieces from here to there :D

Comment: No worries; go with Paul's approach: var query = from n in ctx.News.... and not queryTxt = "Select * from StiriDB.N..."

Comment: A small suggestion for SQL queries, if you would need to create SQL queries in the furture, try to use parameterized queries, it's much saver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Linq to Entities query, something like...

```
public IQueryable<News> GetProducts()
{
    var ctx = new SiteStiri.Models.NewsContext();

    var query = from n in ctx.News
                where n.Description.Contains(SearchTxt)
                select n;

    if ("DesDate".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.ReleaseDate);
    }
    else if ("AsDate".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(u => u.ReleaseDate);
    }
    else if ("AsAlp".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(u => u.NewsTitle);
    }
    else if ("DesApl".Equals(DropDownSelect.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.NewsTitle);
    }

    return query;
}
```